# Remove ^M from ini file

Tags: perl, ini

I have a ini file which is the output of a perl script. The file has ^M in multiple variables. How do I remove them. Pls help!

Ex: ANALOGPORTINFO_16 = 'xxxxxxxxx^M13'

In few lines it's present as the last value.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I use this to strip extraneous carriage returns, linefeeds and tabs... `tr /\r\n\t//d;`

Comment: Do you want to remove the literal string `^M`? Do you want to manipulate the script that creates the file, or alter the file with a different program? In any case, please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: Hi Simbabque,I want to remove the string

Comment: tr /\r\n\t//d; <filename>     correct Mark?

Answer (score 0):

The carriage returns are coming from somewhere, so you need to strip them at the source, e.g. $string =~ s/\r//gs;

if you are on a linux platform, you can also use dos2unix  at the command line, or in perl:

close $file;
system ('dos2unix '.$filename);